# Mouse drags/selects instead of just clicking (like if I had not released the button), only for VirtualBox program

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, mouse

Whenever I click anywhere in Virtualbox's main window (the window that lists your VMs), it starts dragging or selecting, like if I had not released the mouse button:

[image]

In the screenshot above, I performed a left-click (press then release) on the first VM, so it should just be selected. But instead, it is like I was trying to drag the VM somewhere.

Investigation:

- Fearing a hardware problem, I tried using an external USB mouse, but it does not change anything.
- In `Settings`>`Pointing & Clicking`, both `Mouse Keys` and `Click Assist` are `OFF`.
- VirtualBox is the only program where that happens. Right now I am using Firefox and GIMP to take the above screenshot, clicks work perfectly. Clementine (which I believe is another Qt app) also works fine.
- If I start a Windows VM, the problem also occurs inside that Windows environment.
- I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with everything left by default, in particular I have not changed the shell/desktop environment.

How to investigate and fix that?

*VirtualBox version: 5.2.10_Ubuntu r121806 Qt5.9.5*

Comment: I have this problem with both VirtualBox and KVM - sometimes I log out of my session, back in and the problem disappears.  I have not done investigation recently, but I have some lingering suspicions that there are multiple pointing devices (I run a laptop with a touch screen and a mouse) and that these are occasionally conflicted.

Comment: bummer this has never been answered. Still happens. Even after Vbox 6.x upgrades

Comment: Based on the [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133544/139249), it makes me wonder if all hardware with this problem have a touchscreen?

Comment: @mikestewart: I indeed had a touchscreen when I wrote this question.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem recently, both in Virtualbox and Nixnote2 (also a Qt app). Only thing that helped was logging off and back on again.

Comment: I have done this as well, using kvm.  However, this is a comment to the question, rather than an answer!

Comment: I would say it is a valid answer. It is not a definitive solution, but at least it is a workaround.

Comment: This post is more than a month old, I'd rather provide some help than none at all. Also can't comment on others posts since I just signed up to add this.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally I have exactly the same problem with Virtualbox and inside the guest OS as well. Viber desktop client behaves the same, however it is not happening with other apps like Firefox, Thunderbird or other system apps. It mostly happens after returning from suspend mode.

I am using a touchpad, a mouse and have a touch screen display as well. For me it seems the touch screen "stucks" somehow and if I touch/click with it several times it gets me out from this state and Viber/Virtualbox starts working normal again.

And yes, logout/login or restart solves the issue as well, but that's a pain...

Not sure the same issue is causing your problem, but touching/clicking the touch screen worked for me.